# Why image not displaying in corner of textbox by CSS in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc-4

I create one ASP.NET MVC 4 project. I want display an image into textbox like [this tutorial](http://www.cssportal.com/form-elements/text-box.php) but image not display in textbox.

CSS:

```
.searchText {
  background:#FFFFFF url(Images/search.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
  padding:4px 4px 4px 22px;
  border:1px solid #CCCCCC;
  width:230px;
  height:18px;
}
```

View:

```
 <input type="text" class="searchText" />
```

Comment: check your url path is correct or not? here http://jsfiddle.net/53YmR/ it seems working fine for me..

Comment: I would suggest you inspect the CSS class with your browser's developer tools (my personal preference is FireBug), and see if the image is in fact being loaded to the browser. You can also manipulate your CSS direct in the browser to see what works and what doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put a **forward slash** `/` before Images.

Replace this:

> ```
> url(Images/search.png)
> ```

with:

> ```
> url('/Images/search.png')
> ```

Comment: Then Check your image size, the image size may be very bigger.

Comment: ok try doing this :- `background:#FFFFFF url('http://www.cssportal.com/form-elements/images/search.png') no-repeat 4px 4px;`